# Show that there exists a dual space $E^*$ such that the natural injection $E^* \rightarrow L (E)$ is not surjective.

Tags: multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose that $E $ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Show that there exists a dual space $E^*$ such that the natural injection $i:E^* \rightarrow L (E)$ defined by $i(e^*) = \langle - , e^* \rangle : E \rightarrow \Gamma$ is not surjective, where $L (E) $ is the set of linear mappings $\varphi : E \rightarrow \Gamma $.
$ (\langle -,- \rangle$ takes values in  $\Gamma )$

(In my context all vector spaces are defined over a fixed, but arbitrarily chosen field $ \Gamma $ of characteristic $ 0 $)

I know that if $E, E^*$ is a pair of vector space and if a fixed non-degenerate bilinear function, $\langle , \rangle$, in $E^* \times E$ is defined. Then $E$ and $E^*$ will be called dual with respect to the bilinear function $\langle , \rangle $.

I don't know how to use the fact that $ E $ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Could you give me any suggestion please?

A very important theorem in linear algebra that is rarely taught is:

**Theorem:**
A vector space has the same dimension as its dual if and only if it is finite dimensional.

Comment: What kind of field is $\Gamma$?  You say it is ***a*** field.  This sounds like you pick any field (which may not be the base field of your vector space $E$, and which only makes sense if $\Gamma$ is an extension of the base field).  Do you mean $\Gamma$ is ***the base field***?

Comment: @Batominovski  In my context all vector spaces are defined over a fixed, but arbitrarily chosen field $ \Gamma $ of characteristic $ 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $L(E)$ is the “full dual”. Take a basis $B$ of $E$ and, for $v\in B$, define $v^*(v)=1$, $v^*(w)=0$, for $w\in B$, $w\ne v$ and extend by linearity.

Take as $E^*$ the subspace of $L(E)$ spanned by $\{v^*:v\in B\}$.

Comment: I understand the idea but I don't understand very well why define $ v^* (v) = 1 $ and $ v^* (w) = 0 $. Also I don't know who is $ v * $  in your notation. Could you explain a little more please. I'm not that familiar with dual spaces.

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh I'm defining $v^*\in L(E)$ by specifying its values on a basis.

Comment: Is $B$ a Hamel base? I know that any linearly independent set of a vector space can be extended to a base of the space. The family $ \{v^* (v), v^* (w) \} $ is clearly linearly dependent. I still don't understand why $ v^* (v) = 1 $ and $ v^* (w) = 0 $ are defined. What is the set that I must extend to form the dual space $ E ^ * $?

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh First: in order to define a linear map on $E$ you can define its action on a basis; I'm defining $v^*$ to yield $1$ on $v$ and $0$ on all other basis elements. The set $\{v^*:v\in B\}$ is linearly independent in $L(E)$ and it's of course isomorphic to $E$. Since you know that $L(E)$ is not isomorphic to $E$, then $E^*$ is not isomorphic to $L(E)$. Thus the injection $E^*\to L(E)$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: When you say that $ E $ is not isomorphic to $ L (E) $, are you using the following theorem?

**Theorem:**
A vector space has the same dimension as its dual if and only if it is finite dimensional.

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh Yes.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I think it's a very good idea. Although some things are not very clear to me, for example, the fact that $ \{v^* : v \in B \} \cong E $ and the extension that is made I don't understand it very well.